# Add a virtual host dynamically in ejabberd

Tags: hosting, virtual, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

Is it possible to add a virtual host programmatically to ejabberd, without manually editing ejabberd.cfg and restart the server?

I see there are many new features released in latest ejabberd 19.* Like rest APIs, is it plausible to dynamically add virtual via REST APIs.

Answer (score 1):

> I see there are many new features released in latest ejabberd 19.* Like rest APIs, is it plausible to dynamically add virtual via REST APIs.

I don't see any new command to execute to add a new host.

> Is it possible to add a virtual host programmatically to ejabberd, without manually editing ejabberd.cfg and restart the server?

Well, you can edit configuration file programmatically. You probably will prefer to put the hosts option in another file. Example:

In ejabberd.yml

```
include_config_file: /etc/ejabberd/hosts.yml
# hosts
#   - example.org
...
```

In the new file hosts.yml put:

```
hosts:
  - example.org
```

And now you can add new hosts to that config file, and reload all it:

```
$ echo "  - example.net" >> /etc/ejabberd/hosts.yml 
$ ejabberdctl reload_config
```